# Why does my upload code not work?

Tags: php, upload

I'm working on a webpage where you can upload pictures, but the code does not seem to be working. Here is the form code saved as profile2.php:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload2.php" method="POST">
Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Now here is the upload2.php code:

```
<?php
  $target = "pictures/";
  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;
  $uploaded = basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;

  //This is our size condition
  if ($uploaded_size > 1) {
     echo "Your file is too large.<br>";
     die();
  }

  // This is our limit file type condition
  echo $uploaded_type;
  if (!($uploaded_type=="image/png")&&!($uploaded_type=="image/jpg")) {
      echo "You may only upload png or jpg files.<br>";
      die();
  }

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
      echo "The file ". $uploaded ." has been uploaded";
  } else {
      echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
  }
?>
```

So first of all. When I tried to upload a png picture it read the second if statement and said only png and jpg files are allowed. I was expecting it to read the first if statement because my file was greater than 1KB for sure. I have no idea why it ignored the first if statement and did the second if statement. Can anyone help me out on my upload code?

Comment: Is `$upload_size` defined anywhere? If not, how did you expect that to work? Hint: enable error reporting and turn on `display_errors` when developing.

Answer (score 2):

You are blindly assuming that the upload succeeded, and blindly using undefined variables and pretending they actually exist. Perhaps this will help you out:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   if($_FILES['uploaded']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['uploaded']['error']);
   }
   if ($_FILES['uploaded']['size'] > 1) {
      die("File is too large");
      // Are you sure you want "1"? You're basically allowing 1-byte and 0-byte files only
      // since this size is specified in bytes, not kilobytes
   }
   etc...
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php